# API keys are not supported by this API - Google search console error

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-search-console

When I am trying to get the sitemap of my website but it's showing me the following error:

```
{'error': {'code': 401, 'message': 'API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal. See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication', 'errors': [{'message': 'Login Required.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'required', 'location': 'Authorization', 'locationType': 'header'}], 'status': 'UNAUTHENTICATED', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'CREDENTIALS_MISSING', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'method': 'google.searchconsole.v1.SitemapsService.List', 'service': 'searchconsole.googleapis.com'}}]}}
```

It was working when I used Flask and run the project on the browser. I kept the Access token on the flask session as documented by google.

Later I tried to run the app only on the desktop without Flask. So I write an authentication code for the desktop.
here is my new code which is not working:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters']
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'searchconsole'
API_VERSION = 'v1'
def main():
"""Shows basic usage of the People API.
Prints the name of the first 10 connections.
"""
creds = None
# The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN=creds.token
    print(creds.token)
    readSiteMap()
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())
        YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN = creds.token
        readSiteMap()
```

The error is coming from this method:

```
def readSiteMap():
  url="https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/"+WEBSITE+"/sitemaps?key="+API_KEY
  token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
  headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
  headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
  headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer "+token
  headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
  sitemap=requests.get(url=url,headers=headers).json()
  print(sitemap)
  sitemap=sitemap['sitemap'][0]['path']

  xml=requests.get(sitemap).text
  soup=BeautifulSoup(xml,"xml")
  sitemapTags = soup.find_all("sitemap")
  print ("The number of sitemaps are {0}".format(len(sitemapTags)))
  for sitemap in sitemapTags:
    url=sitemap.findNext("loc").text
    if("post" in url):
      sitemaps.append(url)
  print(sitemaps)
```

Please help me fix this problem.
Thank you